# Can not find function fix.dta

Tags: r, arrays

I am trying to follow the code set out in camera trapping for wildlife research, using my own data. I am trying to use the function  `fix.dta()`. I am getting the error message `error in fix.dta, could not find function fix.dta`. I have tried googling the function but can not find anything about it at all. I was hoping someone may know how to help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`.dta` is a file extension for stata files. Maybe you mean `fix.data()` function.

Comment: I have tried that but unfornuatly that does not seem to work either :)

Comment: Then please provide us a minimal reproducible example: see here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>